# Save elicited data on clips language

Tags: database, function, programming-languages, save, clips

I am needing to implement the language clips a way to save all the information elicited, like a database, but I can not do, can assist in please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use a database file and update it whenever needed? Or, do you want to write the data into a file?

For above cases, I would recommend using database. Therefore, using PyCLIPS wight be helpful. You can write Python code and integrate your CLIPS rules in order to update the database.

Hope this helps.

Lorderon

Comment: Use PyClips then. It's good for integrating Python and Clips with sqlite3. There is a need example application here: http://pyclips.sourceforge.net/web/?q=node/25